# Excel vba for exporting cell content to TXT file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file (https://www.dropbox.com/s/hv9u68s136es190/Example2.xlsx?dl=0) with in column A all the persons and in the cell next to there name text (column B).
I want to save for every person a text file containing the text in the cell next to there name.
The filename should be called like the persons name.
So in this case i would have three text files. I do not know how to manage this using VBA in Excel.
Can someone help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, please. But, you must initially try something on your own. We usually help people correct their code and learn...

The text files will be named like the people names in column A. The folder where they will be saved will be the one of the workbook which keeps the active sheet. You can define it as you need, of course.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveTxtNamePlusTekst()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long, strPath As String
  Set sh = ActiveSheet     ' use here the sheet you need
  strPath = sh.Parent.path 'you can define here the path you wish...
  If Dir(strpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MsgBox "The folder path is not valid...": Exit Sub
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row 'Last row in A:A
  For i = 2 To lastR
    'calling a Sub able to create a text file in a folder and put text in it
    WriteText sh.Range("A" & i).value, strPath, sh.Range("B" & i).value
  Next i
End Sub

Private Sub WriteText(strName As String, strPath As String, strText As String)
  Dim filePath As String
  filePath = strPath & "\" & strName & ".txt" 'building the txt file path
  FreeFile 1

    Open filePath For Output As #1
      Print #1, strText 'write the text
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you. I get the error "Invalid filename or invalid file nr".

Comment: @Jose: At what line such an error appear? Do you have people names containing "\", "," or other peculiar characters? Do you test the code on your test file linked here? Do you open the test file directly from mail?

Comment: i tried your code first on my example (so no special markers). And i saved my file on my onedrive, could this be a problem? The one-drive was the problem. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Jose: I adapted the code to previously check if the path is valid... Please refresh the page and use this updated one. But, if it served your need, nobody died when ticked the check box on the code left side... :) Making it the accepted answer, if somebody else will look for such a solution, he will rapidly know which was that...